Virtual Box 7.0 and Ubuntu 24.04.1 Drag and Drop not working
I am currently running an Ubuntu 24.04.1 VM on Oracle Virtual Box 7.0 on Windows 11. My issue is that, even after getting linux-headers installed using the following sets of commands:
$ sudo apt update $ sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y and then installing LinuxGuestAdditions by inserting the virtual CD and navigating to it  by cd /media/user/VBox_GAs_7.0.4/ and running sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run and restarting, Drag and Drop still is not working. I have also enabled Bidirectional for both Copy Paste and Drag and Drop, but it seems like Copy Paste is the only thing that works. I get the following error when I try to drag and drop.
Drag and drop operation from host to guest failed.

DnD: Error: Leaving VM window failed (VERR_TIMEOUT).

Result Code:VBOX_E_DND_ERROR (0X80BB0011)
Component:GuestDnDTargetWrap
Interface:IGuestDnDTarget {50ce4b51-0ff7-46b7-a138-3c6e5ac946b4}
Callee:IDnDTarget {ff5befc3-4ba3-7903-2aa4-43988ba11554}

